# How to know when a fragment is finished loading?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm very very new in android and I have a problem:

I have an app that contains a table
I want to change the table if some calls were stored

Right now I have a call on onResume() but this is called BEFORE the table is fully loaded, so I don't have access to the elements of the table.

When I see the documentation on Resume is the last step called before the fragment is active, I dont know where to call my method to process the calls.

this is the code in ListFragment.java:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (Network.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        processPendingCalls();
    }
}

private void processPendingCalls() {

    Log.v(TAG, "============= processPendingCalls");

    View listview = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.trigger_button);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Call.CallData> entry : Call.CALL_MAP.entrySet()) {
        Customer.CustomerData customer = Customer.CUSTOMER_MAP.get(entry.getKey());
        Call.CallData call = Call.Call_MAP.get(entry.getKey());

        if (call.storedRequest) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Stored request for " + customer.name);
            CompoundButton toggle = (CompoundButton) listview.findViewWithTag(company.id);  // this line breaks!!!
            Log.v(TAG, "(STORED) Toggle View is: " + toggle);
            ProcessManager oom = new ProcessManager(getActivity());
            oom.processCallInBackground(customer, "", "", (CompoundButton) toggle, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Im using a CustomListAdapter to build the table and I can see the debug prints from the processPendingCalls method before the ones from getView method in the CustomListAdapter

This is the error when the processPendingCalls function is called:

```
09-02 15:27:22.648    7562-7562/com.MyApp.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.MyApp.app/com.MyApp.app.ListActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
        at com.MyApp.app.ProcessManager.injectIDs(ProcessManager.java:142)
        at com.MyApp.app.ProcessManager.processCallInBackground(ProcessManager.java:72)
        at com.MyApp.app.ListFragment.processPendingCall(ListFragment.java:133)
        at com.MyApp.app.ListFragment.onResume(ListFragment.java:82)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1543)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1894)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:466)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:455)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onPostResume(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:68)
```

Comment: View listview = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.trigger_button);
Are you sure this is a correct line?
You call a ListView as a view with id trigger_button?

Comment: Yes, is the id it has on the custom_list_adapter.xml it should retrieve a list and then I could be able to make a search by tag

Comment: Actually I have another function almost identical to this one but this is activated by a button when the table is fully loaded and that one works perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the code that populate the table?

Comment: could you override onActivityCreated?  Then call processPendingCalls from there

Comment: I tried overriding onActivityCreated and I got the same result, I just see "Stored request for blabla" before the D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM :(

Comment: I know it is old and probably you have found what was the problem (you should update your Q to reflect it), but it is not where you have pointed the problem is (at least not from the error stack):
the `com.MyApp.app.ProcessManager.injectIDs(ProcessManager.java:142)` is where you should stat to look for error (which is index out of bounds probably here `Call.Call_MAP.get(entry.getKey())`. Check this first.